# Compose functions with different context receivers

Tags: kotlin

I started playing with the new context receivers feature. I intend to use that as a "localized dependency injection" to pass client context around. Currently, I have this (`ClientProvider` is a fun interface):

```
fun <T> withClient(client: Client, block: ClientProvider.() -> T) =
    ClientProvider { client }.block()
```

This works pretty well in the production code, e.g. I can do

```
class MyService {

  context(ClientProvider)
  fun methodUsingClient() {}
}
```

However, an issue arises when I want to `mockk` this code in tests. Currently, I have

```
val myService: MyService = mockk { every { methodUsingClient() } just runs }
```

This obviously doesn't work because the `ClientProvider` context is missing. I would like to fix that by **composing `mockk` and `withClient`**. I imagine it could look like this

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> mockkWithClient(noinline block: context(T) ClientProvider.() -> Unit) =
    mockk<T> { withClient(mockk(), block) }
```

This indeed works at the call site, i.e., the compiler seems to be happy with

```
val myService: MyService = mockkWithClient { every { methodUsingClient() } just runs }
```

but the function itself doesn't compile - the compiler complains about the `block` parameter:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
ClientProvider.() → TypeVariable(T)
Found:
context(T) ClientProvider.() → Unit
```

Intuitively, I would expect that the extra `T` context wouldn't harm the `block` usage inside `withClient` but apparently, it does.

Is there any way how I can define `mockkWithClient` so it can be used as outlined above?

Comment: I've made some progress: If I define `fun <T> withMockClient(block: ClientProvider.() -> T) = ClientProvider { mockk() }.block()`, then I can do `withMockClient { mockk { every ... } }` and the inner block has access to both `ClientProvider` and `T` receivers. This is almost what I want to do except I would like to compose the two blocks into a single `mockkWithClient { every ... }`. Since this seems to be a more general question [I've asked it separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74700995/compose-blocks-with-different-dispatch-receivers)

Answer (score 0):

I got a useful answer to my other, more generally formulated question, and based on that I was able to solve this problem as well (the key point I was missing is that I have to manually pass the receivers to the `block`):

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> mockkWithClient(noinline block: context(ClientProvider) T.() -> Unit) =
  withMockClient<T> { mockk { block(this@withMockClient, this@mockk) } }

fun <T> withMockClient(block: ClientProvider.() -> T) =
  ClientProvider { mockk() }.block()
```

The intended usage is then as expected:

```
mockkWithClient { every { methodUsingClient() }
```

Note, however, the very specific type of `block`: it's `context(ClientProvider) T.() -> Unit`. If I read the [documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/context-receivers.md#functional-types) correctly I should be also able to write `context(ClientProvider, T) () -> Unit` but that doesn't compile with the message `Subtyping relation between context receivers is prohibited`. The root cause of this is still unknown to me but my original problem is solved, nevertheless.