# Compose blocks with different dispatch receivers

Tags: kotlin

Setup:

```
interface AProvider {
    fun getA(): String
}

interface BProvider {
    fun getB(): String
}

fun a(block: AProvider.() -> Unit) {}
fun b(block: BProvider.() -> Unit) {}
```

With this, I can nest the two functions as follows

```
val x = a { b { getA(); getB() } }
```

Now I would like to abstract this particular pattern to a higher level function so that I can pass the inner block and call both `getA()` and `getB()` in it, e.g. something like this:

```
val y = { l: ??? -> a { b(l) } }

val z = y { getA(); getB() }
```

The questions are

- Is this possible with the proposed definition of `y`?
- If yes, what should be the type of `l`?
- If not, is there some other definition where I can get access to multiple dispatch receivers inside a lambda?

Note: This is related to my [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74695263/compose-functions-with-different-context-receivers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [context receivers](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/context-receivers.md), which allows you to specify multiple receivers for one lambda. The type of `y` would be:

```
(context(AProvider, BProvider) () -> Unit) -> Unit
```

That is, a function that takes another function as a parameter, and returns `Unit`. The function parameter that it takes also returns `Unit`, but has `AProvider` and `BProvider` as its context receivers.

```
val y: (context(AProvider, BProvider) () -> Unit) -> Unit = { l -> 
    a { b { l(this@a, this@b) } } 
}

val z = y { getA(); getB() }
```

Notice that when we call `l`, we pass the context receivers, `this@a` and `this@b`, as if they are regular parameters.

This makes `z` a `Unit` as well, which is kind of weird. `y` returns whatever `a` returns after all, so perhaps you did not intend `a` to return `Unit`.

Comment: Yes, that's it! While I knew about context receivers (that was actually the main motivation for this answer) I didn't realize that you need to explicitly pass the contexts to `l`. In hindsight, though, that kind of makes sense although it's not the prettiest syntax (I'm aware of the fact that the whole feature is still in preview).

Comment: Additional question related to [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74695263/compose-functions-with-different-context-receivers): With the technique you suggested I was able to write `inline fun <reified T : Any> mockkWithClient(noinline block: context(ClientProvider) T.() -> Unit) =
    withMockClient<T> { mockk { block(this@withMockClient, this@mockk) } }`.

Comment: This ^ works well but I also tried to wrap both receivers under `context` as in `noinline block: context(ClientProvider, T) () -> Unit`. This is more akin to what you wrote but I got a somewhat cryptic error `Subtyping relation between context receivers is prohibited`. Is this a known issue and if yes what's the reasoning?

Comment: @DavidKubecka perhaps you could edit your original question to ask about this instead, and I can have a look at it when I get back?

Comment: I've included the above-mentioned findings in my original question.